# How to access variable value in test case HTTP method URL

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa, application.properties

I am trying to write Junit test cases for controller classes In spring boot jpa application. In controller class 
`InstituteIdentifier` variable in url I am accessing like this `${InstituteIdentifier}` from `application.property` file. Here I am getting that value in url

In test case also I am accessing `InstituteIdentifier` variable from application.property using `@value` annotation. I am able to print that value in console. But when I am accessing that variable in test case GET method url I am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'InstituteIdentifier`

When I search for this error I found that here `${InstituteIdentifier}` we don't need to give `{}`. when I am removing `{}` variable value is not feaching in url.

Can any one tell me how to do that?

**application.property**

```
InstituteIdentifier=vcufy2010
```

**DepartmenController**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins ="${crossOrigin}")
@RequestMapping("/spacestudy/${InstituteIdentifier}/control/searchfilter")
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService depService;

    @GetMapping("/loadDepartments")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Department>> findDepName() {

        Set<Department> depname = depService.findDepName();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(depname);
    }   
}
```

**TestDepartmentController**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value=DepartmentController.class)
public class TestDepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc  mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    DepartmentService departmentService;

    @Value("${InstituteIdentifier}")
    private String InstituteIdentifier;

    @Test
    public void testfindDepName() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(InstituteIdentifier);//vcufy2010

        Department department = new Department();       
        department.setsDeptName("ABC");


        Set<Department> departmentObj = new HashSet<Department>();
        departmentObj.add(department);

        Mockito.when(departmentService.findDepName()).thenReturn(departmentObj);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/${InstituteIdentifier}/control/searchfilter/loadDepartments")
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I search for this error I found that here ${InstituteIdentifier}
>   we don't need to give {}. when I am removing {} variable value is not
>   feaching in url.

To use the value of a `String` variable, you don't need `{}` nor `$`.
In fact you don't need to evaluate anything. It was already did thanks to `@Value` by Spring.

So in your test, that is correct :

```
@Value("${InstituteIdentifier}")
private String instituteIdentifier;
```

as you need to retrieve the value from the loaded properties.

And then you just need to pass the value of the `instituteIdentifier`  variable in the submitted url by concatenating `String`s  :

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/" + instituteIdentifier +  "/control/searchfilter/loadDepartments")
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working properly. in your ans can you update url. End of + symbol inside double quote `" + instituteIdentifier+" `

Comment: You are welcome :) Question very well asked and simple to understand :) I had noticed the typo and I updated it previously. Is it not fine ? Note that I changed the variable name from `InstituteIdentifier` to `instituteIdentifier` to respect naming conventions.

Comment: yes I didn't notice that naming convention. thank you